# Find all firewalls in Win10

Tags: windows-10, networking, firewall

**Is there any way to view all active firewalls or midware that may be blocking my internet connection ?**

Internet searches a la "[Win10 Find all Firewalls](https://www.google.de/search?q=Win10%20Find%20all%20Firewalls&ei=LXJnYMPGIauA9u8PjJS_0AU&oq=Win10%20Find%20all%20Firewalls&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsANQqOsDWKjrA2Du7gNoAXACeACAAXuIAbYBkgEDMS4xmAEAoAECoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiDkd6vp-DvAhUrgP0HHQzKD1oQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)", "[Win10 installed firewalls](https://www.google.de/search?q=Win10%20installed%20firewalls&ei=7HFnYOLaHc-P9u8Pk8-EmA8&oq=Win10%20installed%20firewalls&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEM0CMgUIABDNAjoHCAAQRxCwA1CjwQNYo8EDYKrFA2gBcAJ4AIABhgGIAYoCkgEDMC4ymAEAoAECoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwjigNuQp-DvAhXPh_0HHZMnAfMQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)" or "[Win 10 active firewalls](https://www.google.de/search?q=Win%2010%20active%20firewalls&ei=bXJnYNSiMPqB9u8PkK-ZyA4&oq=Win%2010%20active%20firewalls&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCAghEBYQHRAeOgcIABBHELADUM7aAVjO2gFg5OABaAFwAngAgAGfAYgB-gGSAQMxLjGYAQCgAQKgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiUja_Op-DvAhX6gP0HHZBXBukQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)" only bring up heaps of pages for the default firewall and how to turn it on

background:

I'm working my way into [Mircosoft's Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor)(Blazor is a framework for building interactive client-side web UI with .NET). When running the test program, which hosts a web page locally, I get a PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR error in Firefox when I access the site via localhost:44344. [Firefox's help](https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1280856) says that there is probably some midware that is breaking the connection.

I did the following things in response:

- refreshed the page → same error message
- restarted the program/server → same error message
- changed browser → Opera shows the error, Edge just refuses the page
- googled the error
- cleared the cache of Firefox and Opera → same error message
- **turned off all firewalls** (after I disconnected from the internet) → same error message
- executed the program on the company's computer → everything works fine there

Now I suspect there is a firewall I don't know about and I would like to find it before resetting my PC.

**Is there any way to view all active firewalls or midware that may be blocking my internet connection, because something is blocking my locally hosted site ?**

**EDIT**

I don't use antivirus programs

Comment: Windows Firewall does not normally block normal activity. Have you tried Resetting the Firewall to Default?  Open Windows Defender, Firewall, and then right side reset to default. That is the simplest thing to do.

Comment: @John I deactivated all firewalls ( private, public and Domain) and the error page persisted, so I conclude that it should not be due to the Win10 firewalls.

Comment: The only other thing I have seen is traffic stopped by Windows Defender (Java updates need to be re-permitted for the Ubiquiti controller written in Java).

Comment: Port 44344 implies local HTTPS which requires the appropriate certificate.  Are you using HTTP or HTTPS? Rational: port 443 is HTTPS, typically one runs a local server on a similar port number, other than what would be used in a real situation.

Comment: That firefox help link is a Q&A indicating antivirus may intercept, are you running any, if so have you tried disabling it temporarily? I doubt that is the issue, but possible. I suspect you have a mis-configuration in your local web server as @Ramhound indicates which provides certificates which is ALSO discussed in that firefox link you provided

Comment: @Ramhound i'm using HTTPS and have a trusted certificate for locahost

Comment: @gregg i am not using any antivirus

Comment: Windows Defender is running if you do not use a Third Party AV. Cannot be removed.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to try:

- [Add *127.0.0.1 localhost* to the *hosts* file](https://bowerwebsolutions.com/how-to-edit-your-local-host-file-for-testing-web-sites/) if it is not defined there, or specify the IP address in the URI, i.e. *https://127.0.0.1:44344*.
- Create *Windows Defender Firewall* Inbound **and** Outbound rules to *Allow the connection*, including specifying port 44344.

[image: Firewall Allow Rule]

- Try a different port, e.g. 80.

Comment: The Inbound and Outbound Rules have solved the problem. Curious as I am, I wonder if there is nevertheless an answer to my original question

Comment: Glad it worked! Windows has increased security over the years, so that by default, a new application does *not* have privilege of going through the firewall.Many communication applications' installation have step where a rule is created, or Windows will pop up a dialog to allow it when an application tries to communicate but *does not* have permission, yet. It seems that step was skipped on one PC, for whatever reason.